# Does material affect friction or physics at all in unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-physics

I have downloaded different materials in unity and added to a ball and it should roll around but it doesn't feel natural, wondering if the material might have affected it in any way, or material is just like skin and has nothing to do with physics?
Thank you.

Comment: Since the rendering materials only take image data, how would they go about and applying friction to the physics component based off of color values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Material`s are used by the graphic renderer.

What you need are `Physic Material` (for 3D physics) and `Physics Material 2D`.